# Insert mySQL query if checkbox checked/not checked with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

During the process of trying to develop an checkbox activated mySQL query based on the value inside a checkbox i've incurred an problem which i can't get past, I've tried the following at the moment

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" onclick="updateStatus(<? echo $data['id']; ?>,this.checked)">
```

The Javascript/Ajax code for the function "updateStatus" is as followed

```
function updateStatus(id,value) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    http = new XMLHttpRequest()
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!")
}
http.abort();
http.open("GET", "../functions/ajax.php?check=update_status&id=" + id + "&checked="+value, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseText);
     }
 }
 http.send(null)
```

The PHP function inside functions/ajax.php

```
if(isset($check) and $check == 'update_status' and isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $checked= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['checked']);
if($checked == true) {
    echo "Checked";
} elseif($checked == false) {
    echo "Not checked";
} else {
    echo "Invalid response";
}
```

when using this code it always returned "Checked" any idea why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox always returning true in javascript/php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282970/checkbox-always-returning-true-in-javascript-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (code tested),

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" onclick="updateStatus(<? echo $data['id']; ?>,this.checked)">
```

You will get second parameter as true or false;

```
function updateStatus(id,checked) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    http = new XMLHttpRequest()
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!")
}
http.abort();
http.open("GET", "../functions/ajax.php?check=update_status&id=" + id+"checked="+checked, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseText);
     }
 }
 http.send(null)
```

You PHP will be:

```
if(isset($check) and $check == 'update_status' and isset($_GET['id']) AND isset($_GET['checked'])){
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$checked= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['checked']);
if($checked == true) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `check_status` WHERE `user_id` = '$_SESSION[userid]' and `id` = '$id'");
else
 //some other query
//Then i can insert the query based on if the checkbox checked or not.
```

Comment: He will also need to update the Javascript function to accept, and then pass the second parameter.

Comment: So my new code would be 
`function updateStatus(id,value) {
 http.abort();
 http.open("GET", "../functions/ajax.php?check=update_status&id=" + id + "&checked=" + value, true);
 http.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
   alert(http.responseText);
  }
 }
 http.send(null)
}`

Comment: @suresh-kamrushi when i do that it's returning true everytime?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="status" onClick="alert(this.checked)"> just see this html in browser and click on it. It will populate with true or false only. Best of luck

Comment: I will go ahead and update my current code to the question so you can understand what i mean, sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: I forgot to update the javascript, please re-read my question, Thank you suresh