# Checkbox always returning true in javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to get the value of the checkbox using an Ajax/Javascript response which passes the value to PHP so i can perform a query based on the value ("Checked","Not checked")

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" onclick="updateStatus(<? echo $data['id']; ?>,this.checked)">
```

The Javascript/Ajax code for the function "updateStatus" is as followed

```
function updateStatus(id,value) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    http = new XMLHttpRequest()
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
} else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!")
}
http.abort();
http.open("GET", "../functions/ajax.php?check=update_status&id=" + id + "&checked="+value, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (http.readyState == 4) {
        alert(http.responseText);
     }
 }
 http.send(null)
```

The PHP function inside functions/ajax.php

```
if(isset($check) and $check == 'update_status' and isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $checked= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['checked']);
if($checked == true) {
    echo "Checked";
} elseif($checked == false) {
    echo "Not checked";
} else {
    echo "Invalid response";
}
```

when using this code it always returned "Checked" any idea why ?

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['checked']`?

Comment: it's passed through the Ajax XMLHttp request

Comment: You were asked about exact value of it. Try `var_dump($_GET['checked'])` to see it in response.

Comment: Don't `mysql_real_escape_string` data until you are about to merge it into a string of SQL. For that matter, don't use it at all, it is from [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: I've gone ahead and changed that for you, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `$_GET['checked']` as a `String`.
Change to something like:

```js
if($checked == "true") {
    echo "Checked";
} elseif($checked == "false") {
    echo "Not checked";
} else {
    echo "Invalid response";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the JS. `value` will be `true` or `false`. When you stringify either of those, you will get a string (`'true'` or `'false'`).

Thus `$_GET['checked']` will be either `"true"` or `"false"` both of which `== true`.

To fix this on the PHP side, compare to the *string* `"true"` and the *string* `"false"`; not the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228827/90648

You can try replacing the code

```
"&checked="+value
```

with

```
(value ? "&checked=true" : '')
```

This way you will only send the value true when it is checked, and not send anything (which you can check in PHP with `isset`)

or you can go with

```
(value ? "&checked=true" : '&checked=')
```

which will again, not send anything, thus empty string will be interpreted as `false`.